# NSDataDetector not finding phone number result type

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to convert this working Objective C code to Swift ([which is based on this Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/))

```
-(BOOL)validatePhone:(NSString*)phone {
    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber
                                                               error:&error];

    NSArray *matches = [detector matchesInString:phone
                                         options:0
                                           range:NSMakeRange(0, [phone length])];

    for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
        if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber) {
            NSString *phoneNumber = [match phoneNumber];
            self.inputPhoneNumber.text = phoneNumber;
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"Phone Number Not Found");
    return FALSE;
}
```

---

Here is my Swift conversion:

```
func validatePhone(phone: NSString) -> Bool {
    var error: NSError?
    let detector = NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingType.PhoneNumber.rawValue, error: &error)

    var matches: NSArray = [detector!.matchesInString(phone as String, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, phone.length))]

    var match:NSTextCheckingResult

    for match in matches{
        if match.resultType == NSTextCheckingType.PhoneNumber{
            inputPhoneNumber.text = match.phoneNumber
            return true
        }
    }

    NSLog("Phone Number Not Found")

    return false
}
```

The `matches` array correctly matches the phone number entered and displays the type correctly as shown here:

[image]

But my `if` statement when checking the result type always returns false

```
if match.resultType == NSTextCheckingType.PhoneNumber
```

Input tested as 555-555-5555 or 5558881234

So, how should I properly check for the NSTextCheckingType?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var text = "555-555-5555"

let types: NSTextCheckingType = .PhoneNumber
var error : NSError?

let detector = NSDataDetector(types: types.rawValue, error: &error)
var matches = detector!.matchesInString(text, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, count(text)))

for match in matches {
   println(match.phoneNumber!)
}
```

In the above code you don't need to check the `resultType` because it only enters in the cycle if match a phone number.

But otherwise, if you want to match more than one type like in the following example :

```
var text = "http://www.example.com"

let types: NSTextCheckingType = .PhoneNumber | .Link
var error : NSError?

let detector = NSDataDetector(types: types.rawValue, error: &error)
var matches = detector!.matchesInString(text, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, count(text)))
```

You can use the following code to check if match one or another:

```
for match in matches {
    if let phone = match.phoneNumber! {
        println(phone)
    }

    if let url = match.URL! {
       println(url)
    }
}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks for also including multiple types as I will also need this later.  Your code helped me to find the problem.  All I needed to do was remove the [] from matches and it worked.  But I also like how you separated the types to make it more readable.